# Copy a specific value to clipboard using VbScript

Tags: vbscript, hta

Below I have my dilemma.  I need to get the txtPreview.Value copied to the clipboard and the end of the UpdatePreview sub.  As it is showing here, I have the sub UpdatePreview to flood specific data and values from other parts of the page to a preview pane, and the button below to run said sub.  I can't seem to get the right combination of things to have the txtPreview.Value copy to the clipboard.

```
Sub UpdatePreview  
    txtPreview.Value =    "Customer/Agency " &_
    vbNewLine & Customer.Value & " / " & AgencyName.value & " #" & AgencyID.value &_
                     vbNewLine &_
                     vbNewLine & "1. QUESTIONS/NEEDS/VALUE" &_
                     vbNewLine & issue1.value &_
                     vbNewLine &_
                     vbNewLine & "2. TROUBLESHOOTING" &_
                     vbNewLine & issue2.value &_
                     vbNewLine &_
                     vbNewLine & "3. SOLUTIONS " &_
                     vbNewLine & issue3.value &_
                     vbNewLine &_
                     vbNewLine & "4. OUTCOME  " &_
                     vbNewLine & issue4.value &_
                     vbNewLine &_
                     vbNewLine                   
End Sub
<input type="button" class="note" value="Preview"  OnClick=UpdatePreview>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<script language=vbscript>
document.write document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("TEXT")

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To put text on the clipboard use `document.parentwindow.clipboardData.SetData "TEXT", txtPreview.Value`